# Create a random even number between range

Tags: c++, random, srand

OK I need to create an even random number between 54 and 212 inclusive. The only catch is that it has to be done in a single statement. I have a class to generate random number within a range, but like I said, I want to do it in a single statement. I came up with this, but it's not working correctly. Any ideas?

```
int main()
{

    srand( time(NULL));
    int i;

    i =  (rand() % 106) * 2;

    cout << i;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this some kind of a homework?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in a single statement? Is this homework?

Answer (score 10):

Generate any number in the interval `[27, 106]` and multiply it by 2. Your problem is that you have no lower bound.

```
int i = 2 * (27 + rand() % (106 - 27 + 1))
```

In general, to generate a random number in `[a, b]` use:

```
int i = a + rand() % (b - a + 1)
```

To see why this works, try simple examples such as `[2, 4]`, `[3, 7]` etc.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic?

Comment: @Goutam - `rand()` generates a random number `>= 0`. Taking it modulo `b - a + 1` will put it in `[0, b - a]`. Adding `a` will put it in `[a, b]`.